# Change Google Organization Inbox Name

Tags: gmail, g-suite-administrator

I'm looking to change the "nickname" of the inbox for my Google organization. I already tried changing the organization's name in the admin page but it still has not changed. I want to change the text in the page title: "_____ Mail" like included in the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. Troubleshooting questions are off-topic here. As the Google Workspace Administrator Help explains, changes might take up to 24 hours to propagate across organization members; on the other hand, some values are stored on the browser cache, and as a Google Workspace administrator, you have access to Google Workspace support from the https://admin.google.com. Considering this, you should try the troubleshooting procedures (check your favorite web browser documentation) and wait up to 24 hours before submitting a support ticket / posting on an online community.

Comment: If you have problems with troubleshooting, you might ask about this on [su] or other [se] sites about computers that allow these questions like might be [apple.se], [ubuntu.se], [unix.se], etc., according to your operative system.